# How to Filtering data using linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How to filter data using linq to sql like:

```
SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE name LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to state more precise questions. Otherwise it is hard for others to awnser your questions. Also always try to do some research on the internet before positng a question. You could have googled this easily.

Comment: @Soner Gönül Did you just reject my edit with this ridiculous and pointless explanation?!

Comment: @bodycountPP You just changed `Filtering` to `filter`. I don't see any improvement whatsoever, so I rejected.

Comment: @SonerGönül, I think grammar improvement counts. It helps getting better search results for one.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from rec in db.Table1 where rec.name.Contains(TextBox1.Text) select rec;
```

Comment: I used it but it always get wrong in where and get this message    "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable to ' An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @HosamElemam: i'm not converting anything. So you need to shpow the code that's causing that exception.